# In locally weighted regression, how determine distance from query point with more than one dimension

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

If the query point in a locally weighted regression is multidimensional (for different features), how do we determine if there are points close-by the query point? This is especially true if the features have different units.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Ah yes. I'm new here and when I added the tag, I didn't realize that it restricted the question to coding implementation only.

Comment: It is not a matter of tags; the tag description is there only to remind yoou of the general site rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x is a vector of the individual differences for each feature, one could use a few different norms to measure the "size" of x (and the distance between any two points). The most commonly used norm is the [L2 norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html). Different normalization schemes could be used but if you scale each feature so that 80% of the points have a value between -10 and 10 you should be OK.